# How to resolve System.ArgumentException: The type 'System.Data.DataTable' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

Getting the below error even if 'System.Data' is referenced

> System.ArgumentException: The type 'System.Data.DataTable' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

Comment: Project > Add Reference > Assemblies tab on the left > Type "System.Data" in search bar > Select it > Add > Should work fine

Comment: @Tamás Szabó : System.Data is included in the references from C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\

Comment: Does this happen during compilation?

Comment: @TamásSzabó : Yes its during compilation

Comment: And the dll is there where the path shows, and it is the correct version (4.0.0.0)?

Comment: @TamásSzabó : Yes version is correct its 4.0.0.0

Comment: Does you solution contain more than one project?

Comment: Yes @chrisdunaway solution has many projects

Answer (score 1):

Realise this is an old issue but to save someone time if they find this issue:

1. Close Visual Studio.
2. Delete the .vs folder for the solution.
3. Open Visual Studio and problem is fixed.